# Separate out global functions into own file?

Tags: swift

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119815/sprite-kit-swift-2-tutorial-for-beginners) to get started on some basic game programming in Swift. I've completed said tutorial but want to refactor what I've done, and I would like to know if there's a way to store global functions (example included below) in their own file that I then include somehow for use in my GameScene class.

```
func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}
```

Currently there's a few of these overloaded operators sitting in the same file as my GameScene class, but declared outside of it, and it feels messy/bloated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them into a separate Swift file. Swift functions (and also classes, structs, enums, etc.) are `internal` by default which means that they can be used from anywhere within the same module. As long as the new file belongs to the same module, there's no need to import anything.

You can find more on this topic here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Comment: Oh god... I can't believe it's that simple! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension. In your case, you would add the extension to any viewController file. The extension can not be celled within the viewController class, in other words, you add the extension after the last curly brace "}" at the bottom of your code. Here is what I would use:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}
}
```

You can then call the function in any viewController class in that project.